# Функция которая вычисляет среднее значение чисел, reduce

Tags: javascript

Почему в конце `||` (или) `0`?

```
const find_average = array => array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0) / array.length || 0;
```

[Ката](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57a2013acf1fa5bfc4000921/train/javascript)

Comment: Скорее всего для тех случаев, когда массив пустой. То есть `0 / 0` - `NaN`. Вместо того, чтобы возвращать `NaN`, возвращается 0.

Answer (score 1):

По условию. Note: Empty arrays should return 0.

При пустом массиве у вас reduce вернёт 0. Вы его поделите на 0 и получите NaN. Поскольку это falsy значение, то сработает `|| 0` и вернётся 0.